# Mulitcore or Clock Speed

Tags: apache, server

For programs like Apache, do they work better with more threads, or due to their asynchronous handling of requests make it so they handle better with a higher clock speed?

Comment: Interesting question. I say, both. Clock speed and CPU/CPU Cores are contributing factors as to how many processes from the compute queue can be handled and how quickly these processes complete. As well, keep in mind that there are other OS tuning metrics that can be changed to help specific applications such as Apache such as Quorum. The simplest thing you can do for a busy Apache install is to tune the application itself which may include how may resident/ready Apache processes are available to handle requests. Do not over-think it, however. Just get a fast machine.

Comment: Looking at your title, for an extremely busy site, I would opt for cores. The more cores, the likely it will be a fast CPU too. So it is a bit of a *get two for the price of one*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how your Web app is built and what it does when it is running.

If your app is running on a server with dual-core 2GHz and it is only using 50% of the CPU at all times, then going to a quad-core 3GHz is not going to improve the app’s performance. It may be to get that app to run better, you have to give it more RAM, or faster storage, or bigger bandwidth.